# sum(case When.. AND) with multiple conditions not working

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to run this sum query to produce two columns of Turnover one for TY and another for LY. However, I want any transactions flagged as Cancelled to appear as negatives:

```
select [Location],BR.BranchName, 
 sum(case when (FX.TransactionDateKey between '20171101' and '20181031') 
   and ([Action] = 'Cancelled') 
   then FX.CustomerValue*-1  else [CustomerValue] end) as [CustmVal TY],
 sum(case when (FX.TransactionDateKey between '20161101' and '20171031') 
   and ([Action] = 'Cancelled')
   then FX.CustomerValue*-1 else FX.CustomerValue*1 end) AS [CustmVal LY]
from [dbo].[FRX_Transactions] FX
inner join DWX_Branch BR on BR.BranchID=FX.[Location]
where FX.TransactionDateKey between '20161101' and '20181031' and BR.BusinessDivision = 'Retail'
and FX.[Action] in ('Trade','cancelled') and FX.Reason in ('Public','BBG','Overridesupplyrate') and FX.Operation in ('Add','Del')
group by FX.[Location],BR.BranchName, BR.BranchOpenDate,BR.BranchCloseDate,BR.ActiveStatus
order by BR.BranchName
```

However, when I run it I get similar data in both columns - it seems to ignore the date conditions.
Please, what am I doing wrong? Is this case-when-statement with TWO conditions written wrong?

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated. Massive thanks!

Comment: So, when `Action` isn't "cancelled" you want to sum all customer values regardless of the date range?   Because that's what this code would do.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want for your `CASE` expression is:

```
CASE WHEN FX.TransactionDateKey BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20181031' THEN [CustomerValue] *
                                                                       CASE WHEN [Action] = 'Cancelled' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
END
```